# Removing duplicates from Django Lists

Tags: django

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I cannot seem to work this out! :/

My application populates a list of files in a folder. It then querys a database and creates a query set of the file names.

I want the lists to be merged, then the duplicates removed. The final list will be then be listed out on a template and will this consist of files that are in the folder but haven't been added to the database,

Views.py:

```
def Image_Add(request):
    path="..."
    images =os.listdir(path)
    usedimage=Images.objects.values('imageurl').distinct()
    result=[]

    for image in images:
        result.append(image)

    for image2 in usedimage:
        result.append(image2)

    imagelis=set(result)
    imagelist=list(imagelis)

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'Image_Add.html', {'form':imagelist})
```

However on the template all of the files are being displayed without the duplicates removed.
(I am currently getting an error on the line  "`imagelis=set(result)`")

thanks you

Comment: Why are you converting to a set and then back to a list? Also, what's the error you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
usedimage=Images.objects.values_list('imageurl', flat=True).distinct()
```

instead of

```
usedimage=Images.objects.values('imageurl').distinct()
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

`values()` returns dicts which is unhashable type. This causes error.

Answer (score 2):

```
usedimage=Images.objects.values_list('imageurl', flat=True).distinct()

for image in usedimage:
    Images.objects.filter(pk__in=Images.objects.filter(imageurl=imageurl
        ).values_list('id', flat=True)[1:]).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

As catherin said you can filter in django quesy itself .

Alternatively to remove duplicates you try  sets 
Here is an example .

```
import sets
t = sets.Set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
t1 = sets.Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

print t | t1
print t - t1
```